# Can we derive $N=aa^{\dagger}$ from these conditions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Let $[a,b]:=ab-ba$ for all $a,b\in X$ a non commutative ring. Suppose that $a,a^{\dagger},N$ are operators satisfying
$$\begin{align}
[a,a^{\dagger}]&=1 \\
[N,a]&=-a \\
[N,a^{\dagger}] &= a^{\dagger}
\end{align}$$
where $1$ is simply the identity operator and $a^{\dagger}$ is the physicist's adjoint of $a$.

> Does it follow that 
>   $$
> N=aa^{\dagger} 
> $$
>   just from these $3$ conditions?

**Motivation**: My friend ask me a related question, which can be easily solve if the above is true. The $3$ conditions are simply given at the very beginning of the exercise. If we interpret $N$ as the **number operator**, $a$ as the **annihilation operator** and $a^{\dagger}$ as the **creation operator** then it is generally known that $N=aa^{\dagger}$. So I wonder if his professor simply forgot to write that in the exercise sheet or if the fact can be derived.

Comment: What is "the physicist's adjoint"?

Comment: @rschwieb Just like normal adjoint, but written $a^{\dagger}$ instead of $a^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that  $N$ is positive, the second condition is just a restatement of the second one. If you multiply the first condition by $-a$ on the left you get the second condition for $N=a^{\vphantom\dagger} a^\dagger$. So $N=a^{\vphantom\dagger} a^\dagger$ is certainly a solution. The question is whether it is unique.

This boils down to the question of whether $Xa-aX=0$ implies $X=0$. Such condition certainly doesn't follow from the given conditions. Actually, $X=\lambda I$ will always commute with $a$, so $N=a^{\vphantom\dagger} a^\dagger+\lambda I$ will satisfy the equations for all $\lambda\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: In physics one also requires that there exist a vector $v_0$ such that  $av_0=0$. This might narrow things down, though I don't remember off the top of my head. For instance, the first commutation relation imposes $v_0=(aa^\dagger-a^\dagger a) v_0 = a a^\dagger v_0$, so when $N=aa^\dagger+\lambda I$ one has $Nv_0=(1+\lambda)v_0.$

Comment: @Semiclassical That's pretty interesting, I'll think about that.